# How to send huge JSON from body inside request? Jmeter

Tags: apache, testing, jmeter

I want to test request which is sending JSON using body. How it looks in DevTools:
[image]

So i am clicking "view source" and i am coping whole that code.
Next stage is to paste that code into "Body Data" in my HTTP Request (JMeter). 
After 15 minutes of waiting i am able to see that result:
[image]

but JMeter is frozen as f... I have huge lag. This JSON is to much for this.
**How can i paste something like that without this lag?**

When i am trying to paste coded version it is pasted without lags. But as i can see coded version do not work :( i need to paste that json from "view source"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the JSON into a file like `payload.json` and store this file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

Once done you can load the file in JMeter script via [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

```
${__FileToString(payload.json,,)}
```

[image]

This way you will be able to manage your script easier.

---

Going forward you can optimize even more via [HTTP Raw Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it/) which has nice [feature of directly streaming the file to the endpoint without loading it into memory first](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html), check out [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w) discussion for more information.